# VS Code: Azure workspace folders do not appear after I run a function

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, openai-api, chatgpt-api

In VS Code in Windows 10, using python 3.9.13, I run a function and it just returns paths in the terminal. The call stack appears for an instant in the left margin and disappears, then "No local workspace resources exist" appears where my workspace folder should be. I ran this function several times in previous days without this issue.
I want to deploy the function but I can't because there is nothing under Workspaces. The image is a screenshot of what it does after I run the function.[image]

Comment: Open **BasicAzureFunction** in an **Integrated terminal** in VS Code and run > **func host start** in your terminal for your Function to run.

Or else, Just open BasicAzureFunction folder in VS Code > And click on fn + f5 or Run > start Debugging.

Your function will be triggered> Do not open entire Udemy folder, Just open BasicAzureFunction in your Vs  Code

Comment: I changed the prompt path in the terminal to the BasicAzureFunction folder, ran the function, and it complained there was no connection. Then ran the function from the  child folder where the function lives, then again from BasicAzureFunction and that's when it executed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open **BasicAzureFunction** in an **Integrated terminal** in VS Code and run > **func host start** in your terminal for your Function to run.
- Or else, Just open BasicAzureFunction folder in VS Code > And click on fn + f5 or Run > start Debugging.
- Your function will be triggered> Do not open entire Udemy folder, Just open BasicAzureFunction in your Vs Code.
- If that doesnot work run the function from the child folder where the function is present and then run function from **BasicAzureFunction** and it will run the function.